# JMeter - Result Analysis . Reponse time overhead issue

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am  running a JMeter load test  with 5 URL hits under a transaction controller .
The results shows overall avg response time (summary report listener) as 34647 ms (~35 seconds).
On checking the  individual avg response time of each URL hits , all are less than 1.5 seconds .It doesn't sum up to he overall response time of 35 seconds .
I have added a constant timer of 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

At what level is your constant timer? Do you have multiple samplers in a transaction controller and the timer is attached to the transaction controller(with option selected to include think time)? If so then, that may be the cause.

As per documentation -

Note that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found; if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed before each sampler.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers

Comment: My timer is for the transaction controller to slow down the iteration and prolong it for a certain time . Does timer gets added to the response time displayed in Summary report

Comment: If you have selected to exclude the timer response time check box on transaction controller setting, it would not be accounted in the response time report. Please ensure you have enabled and checked that option.

Comment: Yes I have deselected the option to include timer during the test . Are there any other overhead that can cause this mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Your Constant Timer is being executed **before** each Sampler as it's being applied to all the samplers in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/)

[image]

If you need to introduce the delay of 5 seconds **after** the Transaction Controller - go for [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action).

This way you will have 5 seconds delay between 2 Transaction Controllers:

[image]

Comment: I added Flow Control action to a thread through with 3 transaction controllers each with more than 5 hits  . On a prolonged run , I could see overhead . I performed two tests, one with flow control action and one without  . On checking results , the one with flow control action had response time atleast avg 10-20 seconds more than  the test without flow action control